# Representations of scalar fields from the expressions of fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, representation-theory

Consider scalar field $\phi(x)$, when we quantize this scalar field we get an expression in terms of creation and annihilation operators as $\phi(x) = \sum c(p)({ae^{ipx} + a^\dagger e^{-ipx}} )$. If I have a field with $a(k) \to e^{i\theta}a(k)$ . How do I find representations of the changed field ?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example where this question came up? Because I don't quite understand what you mean...

Comment: The only thing I can really say is the number operator N is invariant. It would be nice to have a Lagrangian.